# Any calls to DJISDKManager results in fatal crash with no errors or exceptions - 4.11

Tags: android, androidx, dji-sdk

I recently updated our app to use AndroidX and DJI SDK 4.11 which included updating those versions:

```
DJI SDK from 4.10 to 4.11
compileSdkVersion from 27 to 28
ext.kotlin_version from 1.2.61 to 1.3.41
com.android.tools.build:gradle from 3.2.1 to 3.4.1
gradle from 4.6 to 5.1.1
```

added

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

I also included in gradle file and in manifest file

```
gradle:
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}

manifest:
<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
```

to fix an exception with DJI SDK using legacy http calls

However, when I make *any* call to DJISDKManager such as getInstance(), it crashes without any errors or exceptions.  This is on debug, so proguard shouldn't be stripping out anything important at this point.  I've scoured the internet trying to find different answers or possibilities, and have made the above changes which fixed different issues, but this one I'm stumped on.  Anyone have similar experiences and figured out workarounds?

Edit: I enabled Java Exception Breakpoints and Exception Breakpoints, and got this exception: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: wrap that call in `try` & `catch` ...or manually set a break-point and then proceed in single step.

Comment: I have tried that, but the fatal exception just kills the application. The catch doesn't catch it, it just closes the program.  Stepping through the line abruptly disconnects the debugger and the program gets into a loop where it crashes, then starts again then crashes again.

Comment: Java barely crashes without the least information... try filtering logcat output. Or does the project include native assembly, written in C/C++? This nevertheless still should log something when crashing... the current exception message just means, that some file or directory is missing.

Comment: Not sure what he mean by "next release", but androidx should be supported with it:
https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/issues/438#issuecomment-533087922 (there's several issues filed with androidx and also disconnect).

Comment: As of DJI 4.11, AndroidX is supported. That is the "next release" that was being referred to.

I edited on bottom in original post that I enabled Java/General exception breakpoint so if any gets thrown it'd hit a breakpoint. I was able to get the following error: 
android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

However I am unable to figure out what it is trying to open, and it seems to be called from when DJISDKManager (a singleton) is first used causing a crash. I have verified that the app have WRITE/READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission first before the call

Comment: This likely might be the log-file location on-device; maybe an absent micro SD?

Comment: I dug into decompiled code, and found this:
`
    static {
        String var10000 = "sfjni";

        try {
            System.loadLibrary(var10000);
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError var0) {
            var0.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("sfjni", "Couldn't load lib");
        }

    }
`
I will continue research.  In the past, it wasn't required to have an active connection to the drone, it would simply register the DJI component and prepare it for connecting to actual drone.  I will also test having an active drone connection and see if it helps.

Comment: It's loading native library `sfjni.so` ...updating the firmware might possibly help - or simply file a new issue on GitHub (I don't have any such device to test, so I can only make suggestions).

Answer (score 1):

This configuration is working, I can verify...

build.gradle: 3.5.1. (Crash if you use 3.5
2)

Kotlin: 1.3.50

buildToolsVersion 29.0.2

compileSdkVersion 29

Also, check packageOptions, they changed,  verify against sample

You might also need to add permission for RECORD_AUDIO, there was a note about this but I cannot find it now.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestions.  Having it at SDK version of 29 crashes the app, so I reverted to 28, but all others are updated as per your suggestions.  However, when I build the release version, it seems like something got stripped, despite me matching the proguard rules and the package options from the sample application, so it crashes when I call this (it works fine in debug build):

DJISDKManager.getInstance().registerApp(context, productManager)

Comment: Gradle version was the Key for me here. Anything above 3.5.1 causes the exact issue posted.

Comment: Yes, DJI has not kept their Proguard rules updated and over the months of repeated requests they still have not provided the details required to allow Proguard to function properly.

It would be nice if they (DJI) would build the Proguard rules into the library like most professional libraries do these days but so far not luck getting that either.